# Modeling dependent events

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian, monte-carlo

Say we have event A (saving a life) and event B (person living after initially getting saved). A and B are dependent events as p(A|B) = 1. I want to model the probability of a person living which is p(A)p(B). However, since B is dependent on A = 1 the data is limited and noisy. I was wondering if I could use STAN or any other modelling technique to fit a distribution on this to calculate p(A) and p(B) separately (or in a single model) and get a single distriution of p(A)p(B). Is this possible?

Edit: Let's say we have patients [x1,x2,...] and surgeries [s1,s2] then I want to model probability of life saved for each treatment: p((A=1 and B=1) | s1) and p((A=1 and B=1) | s2). My train of thought is that Is should break these down. So, given s = s1 then p((A=1 and B=1) | s1) becomes p(A=1)*p(A=1 and B=1). If I could model these two multiples separately

Comment: I think there must be missing information.  Presumably some people live without needing to have their lives saved, right?  More broadly, if $B$ is so rare that there is no good data on it, I don't know what statistics is going to do for you.

Comment: I don't see that the supposed dependence matters much...$B$ can only happen if $A$ has happened, it isn';t really an event on its own, right?  Well, that's fine...just divide $A$ into two disjoint events...$A_1$ in which the person's life is saved and they continue to live and $A_2$ in which the person's life is saved but they don't continue to live (not that I really understand what you mean by that...how was my life saved if I don't continue to live?)

Comment: @lulu let me clarify. The set only contains people who initially came to the hospital i.e event A has happened (either A = 1 life saved or A =0 life not saved). If A=0, then B can't happen (how can you later save anyone if they died in the first place). If A=1, then B comes into play. After initially getting saved (assuming through a surgery), does the patient live up till 14 days or not (B=1 he/she lives and B=0 is death). So, the quantity I'm interested in modelling is the global probability of a patient getting saved i.e (1-p(A=0 or (A=1 and B=0))

Comment: Ok, so my separation of $A$ into two disjoint events works.   It seem that you have three exhaustive and mutually exclusive events:  Either the patient dies at once, they don't die at once but they do die within some stated time interval, or the patient survives longer than the stated interval.

Comment: The two sources of death i.e (A=0 or (A=1 and B=0)) have different behaviours. I might be wrong (and please suggest me something here) but I believe it is better to model p(A) and p(B=1|A=1) separately (or in a single model as separate entities) and then combine them together. p(B=1|A=1) cases are noisy but I believe using STAN priors on the treatment used to get A=1 could help the cause here. However, I'm confused as to how to formalize the p(A)p(B) (or p(A)p(B=1|A=1) bayesian model

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to model.  It seems that you have three exhaustive, mutually exclusive events and you ought to be able to estimate their respective probabilities from the sample.  Beyond that, what are you looking for?

Comment: Let's say we have patients [x1,x2,...] and surgeries [s1,s2] then I want to model probability of life saved for each treatment: p((A=1 and B=1) | s1) and p((A=1 and B=1) | s2). My train of thought is that Is should break these down. So, given s = s1 then p((A=1 and B=1) | s1) becomes p(A=1)*p(A=1 and B=1). If I could model these two multiples separately

Comment: Sorry, it's just not clear.  Say the treatments are $t_1, t_2$ and my three possible outcomes are $A_0(t_i), A_1(t_ )$  we can use the sample date to estimate the six values.  I can then hope to use statistics to decide something like "can we rule out the possibility that the two treatments are equally effective?"  Now that often hits bad problems if the sample size is small, but that's life.  Math can't find things that aren't in the data.

Comment: I might have been vague in formulating the problem but let me rephrase
We have certain treatments available for a particular disease. We know as a fact that the treatment effects are different and one is better than the other on saving the patient "ON THE DAY" i.e at day=0. However, the treatment that saves more patients on the day, often times those patients still die within days=14 (so that treatment actually didn't work). I'm interested in seeing if this treatment really just stalls the death or is actually a good treatment and those later deaths are just noise.

Comment: I tried instead of using days=0 outcomes I used days=14 outcomes to model but the results had different results on different folds making me wonder if there is noise existing in days=14 outcomes (i.e it could be that patients died because of lack of care and wasn't tied to the treatment). It all boils down to figuring out if there is signal in the noisy days=14 data and extracting that signal and combining it with days=0 outcomes to picture the true usefulness of the treatment

Comment: My train of thought here is that I might not have sufficient-ish data for all treatments but I have sufficient data for some treatments and then all the data (with all the treatments) is a lot of data on which I can fit a global prior to cater for low data in some low evidence treatments. Hope I'm clear

Comment: I can't imagine a model that allows you to extrapolate data for new treatments, but I guess it's theoretically possible. As with any model, the idea would be to describe the model in detail (with unknown parameters) and then calibrate those parameters with the data you have.  But designing the problem is a medical issue, not a mathematical one.